# When is $a^b$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and laws of exponents defined?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The title basically says it all, I can't seem to find a reliable source to understand when is something like $a^b$ is defined, like what set of values $a$ and $b$ are allowed to take? Everything is defined and laws of exponents work fine whenever $a,b>0$ (or at least I think so, correct me if I'm wrong) but you can see we immediately start running into trouble when $a$ becomes negative or $b$ is a fraction where denominator is a multiple of $2$ etc.

For instance, $a= -1$ and $b= \frac{1}{4} $ then $(-1)^{1/4}$ is not defined in $\mathbb{R}$ but $(-1)^{1/3}$ is, even when the base is negative. And laws of exponents like $(a^m)^{n}= a^{mn}$ or $(ab)^n = a^n b^n$ don't hold.

So hopefully, I've expressed my confusion well. I don't understand that sometimes $a$ can be less than $0$ sometimes not? Similarly for $b$. How do I know when are the laws defined?

In short, my question:

> What is the range of $a$ and $b$ in $\mathbb{R}$ so that $a^b$ is defined in $\mathbb{R}$ and for what values to the laws work?

Thank you for reading such a long text. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Terence Tao's Analysis Text Book (Volume 1) is a nice help. He defines, step by step, exponentiation up to $x^y$ where $x$ is a positive real number and $y$ is any real number. When $x$ is negative, we need to move to complex numbers(which is not in the text).

Comment: @1.414212 Alrighty, thanks. I needed a source too.

Answer (score 2):

Define $a^b = e^{b\log a}$.  This works for complex numbers $a\ne 0$ and $b$.  But it has multiple values if $b$ is not an integer.  If $a>0$ we can choose a "principal" value by choosing $\log a$ to be real.

As the OP noted, trying to get $(-1)^{1/3} = -1$ is very complicated to do when we work only with real numbers.  So mathematicians moved on the complex numbers, where things were much better.

Comment: And what about the laws of exponents? Actually the reason I ask this question is because I'm about to start learning complex numbers, so before I do. I just wanna make sure I understand why do I need to study them. You know a good place to start?

Comment: The laws of exponents hold over $\mathbb{C}$. Complex numbers are overall much nicer to work with than only looking at $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: When we work with real numbers, many of the laws of exponents require that the base be positive. For example: if $a>0$ then  $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$, but $a = (a^2)^{1/2}$ fails when $a<0$.

Comment: @Nurator I see, but it's still nice what exactly "stops" real numbers from doing that hence my question. :)

Comment: @William Its hard to explain that without basic understanding what complex numbers are. I would suggest you read more into the topic and then you will be able to answer that question yourself :)